# Multiples insert en relación uno a uno laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-7

Tengo la tabla "Usuario" relacionada a "Redes Sociales" en relación uno a uno, donde el id de la tabla Redes sociales es el mismo de la tabla Usuario.
En la interfaz primero se crea el usuario y posteriormente el puede editar su perfil donde cabe mencionar viene toda la información de la tabla de usuario y redes sociales en un mismo formulario y agregar las redes sociales, ahí se crearía un registro con su id en caso de no existir.
Quisiera saber como puedo hacer un update multiple, es decir actualizar mi tabla de usuario y también la tabla de redes sociales en caso de existir información ya que solo he logrado actualizar la información de la tabla de usuario de la siguiente manera:

```
public function actualizar(Request $request, $id)
{
    $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

    
    $usuario->update($request->all());
        
    return redirect('usuario/perfil')->with('mensaje', 'Usuario actualizado exitosamente');
}
```

En mi modelo de usuario tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function redes_sociales() {
    return $this->hasOne(RedesSociales::class,'id');
}
```

En mi modelo de Redes Sociales, lo siguiente:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class);
}
```

Ya intente hacer un update de la siguiente manera:

$usuario->redes_sociales->update(array_filter($request->all()));

pero consigo un error de primera mano porque me incluye el method y el _token, ya hice el except pero me arroja un error porque intenta insertar la información que debería ir en la tabla de usuario, en la tabla de redes sociales

Comment: Pero exactamente que intentas actualizar en redes sociales?

Comment: Son 4 campos que estan en redes sociales

Comment: Tengo una consulta, que datos obtienes de `$request->all()` para que le pases a `array_filter`

Comment: @IsraelGutierrez entonces ¿si por ejemplo el usuario actualiza información de su red social quieres que se actualice ese registro en relación solo con el usuario al que pertenece?

Comment: Me parece que tu relación está mal. Varias redes sociales pertenecen a un usuario? Entonces no sería una relación uno a uno. Además no deberías colocar que la relación es por medio de la ID, deberías crearle un campo a red_social que se llame user_id.

Comment: Es una tabla que contiene 4 redes sociales esperadas, es por eso que se extendió la tabla Redes sociales para no tener que agregarla directamente en la tabla de usuario